# 'Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.'

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

this is a piece of a code in my DataBase Class :

```
public static int ChangeTable(string strSql , string strFileName)
{
   OleDbConnection c = new OleDbConnection();
   c = MakeConnection(strFileName);
   OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strSql, c);
   int nAffectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   c.Close();
   return nAffectedRows;
}
```

and it is used in my Users Class as following:

```
public int AddUser(string fname, string lname , string email, string password)
{
    string strSql = "INSERT INTO [users] ([email] , [password] , [fname] , [lname]) VALUES ('" + 
email + "''" + password + "''" + fname + "''" + lname + "');";
    string dbname = "DataBase.mdb";
    int didItWork = Dbase.ChangeTable(strSql, dbname);
return didItWork;

}
```

whenever I run it this error pops up:

> "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.'"
>   and it always backcolors the command "int nAffectedRows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();"

I have no idea what's wrong, this is my first website project, i could really use some help.

p.s I'm using asp.net (it's a school homework).

Comment: You're missing commas between your values.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the header of your insert does not match the number of values passed here:

```
 string strSql = "INSERT INTO [users] ([email] , [password] , [fname] , [lname]) VALUES ('" + 
    email + "''" + password + "''" + fname + "''" + lname + "');";
```

Correct will be, adding a *comma* between values:

```
 string strSql = "INSERT INTO [users] ([email] , [password] , [fname] , [lname]) VALUES ('" + 
    email + "','" + password + "','" + fname + "','" + lname + "');";
```

Better even is to use parameters instead:

```
string strSql = "INSERT INTO [users]([email],[password],[fname],[lname]) 
                  VALUES (@email,@password,@fname,@lname);";

cmd.CommandText = strSql;

// add named parameters
cmd.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[]
{
    new OleDbParameter("@email", ...),
    new OleDbParameter("@password", ...),
    ...
});

// execute
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: The best option is with parameters to prevent Sql Injection